# Add constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, nslayoutconstraint

I have 5 buttons I want to place on screen programmatically.

I want them to be 17px above the bottom of the view, and 20px space between every button.

I've done that like this:

```
let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(20, 48, 50, 50))
button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "button1"), forState: .Normal)

let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(91, 48, 50, 50))
button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "button2"), forState: .Normal)

let button3 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(162, 48, 50, 50))
button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "button3"), forState: .Normal)

let button4 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(233, 48, 50, 50))
        button4.setImage(UIImage(named: "button4"), forState: .Normal)

let button5 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(304, 48, 50, 50))
button5.setImage(UIImage(named: "button5"), forState: .Normal)

self.addSubview(button1)
self.addSubview(button2)
self.addSubview(button3)
self.addSubview(button4)
self.addSubview(button5)
```

I works great and exactly what I want! But just on iPhone 6s screen size, so I guess the way to make it work on all screen sizes is using constraints, the problem is that I don't have an idea how can I add constraints programmatically.

Can someone help me here?

Thank you!

**SaintThread answer, log error:**

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d968a10 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729670.midX == + 45>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725610 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79729670]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797255e0 H:[UIButton:0x79729670(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797255e0 H:[UIButton:0x79729670(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.305 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d968a10 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729670.midX == + 45>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725610 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79729670]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725610 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79729670]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.305 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96a3c0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729670.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725c50 V:|-(20)-[UIButton:0x79729670]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725ad0 V:[UIButton:0x79729670(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725ad0 V:[UIButton:0x79729670(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.306 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96a3c0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729670.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96a3f0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIButton:0x79729670(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725c50 V:|-(20)-[UIButton:0x79729670]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725c50 V:|-(20)-[UIButton:0x79729670]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.306 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a991c60 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729080.midX == + 116>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725560 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79729080]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725510 H:[UIButton:0x79729080(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725510 H:[UIButton:0x79729080(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.306 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a991c60 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729080.midX == + 116>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a991c90 h=--& v=--& H:[UIButton:0x79729080(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725560 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79729080]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725560 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79729080]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.307 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96a3c0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729670.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96a3f0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIButton:0x79729670(50)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a991cc0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729080.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725a10 V:[UIButton:0x79729670]-(20)-[UIButton:0x79729080]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797259e0 V:[UIButton:0x79729080(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797259e0 V:[UIButton:0x79729080(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.307 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96a3c0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729670.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96a3f0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIButton:0x79729670(50)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a991cc0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729080.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725a10 V:[UIButton:0x79729670]-(20)-[UIButton:0x79729080]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725a10 V:[UIButton:0x79729670]-(20)-[UIButton:0x79729080]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.307 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96b720 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79728480.midX == + 187>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725490 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79728480]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725440 H:[UIButton:0x79728480(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725440 H:[UIButton:0x79728480(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.308 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96b720 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79728480.midX == + 187>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96b750 h=--& v=--& H:[UIButton:0x79728480(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725490 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79728480]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725490 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79728480]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.308 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a991cc0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729080.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a991cf0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIButton:0x79729080(50)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96c260 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79728480.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797259b0 V:[UIButton:0x79729080]-(20)-[UIButton:0x79728480]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725980 V:[UIButton:0x79728480(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725980 V:[UIButton:0x79728480(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.308 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a991cc0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79729080.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a991cf0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIButton:0x79729080(50)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96c260 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79728480.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797259b0 V:[UIButton:0x79729080]-(20)-[UIButton:0x79728480]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797259b0 V:[UIButton:0x79729080]-(20)-[UIButton:0x79728480]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.309 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7aad76b0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79727bc0.midX == + 258>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797253b0 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79727bc0]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725380 H:[UIButton:0x79727bc0(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725380 H:[UIButton:0x79727bc0(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.309 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7aad76b0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79727bc0.midX == + 258>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7aad76e0 h=--& v=--& H:[UIButton:0x79727bc0(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797253b0 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79727bc0]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797253b0 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x79727bc0]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.309 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96c260 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79728480.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96c290 h=--& v=--& V:[UIButton:0x79728480(50)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7aad7710 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79727bc0.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725950 V:[UIButton:0x79728480]-(20)-[UIButton:0x79727bc0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725920 V:[UIButton:0x79727bc0(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725920 V:[UIButton:0x79727bc0(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.309 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96c260 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79728480.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d96c290 h=--& v=--& V:[UIButton:0x79728480(50)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7aad7710 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79727bc0.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725950 V:[UIButton:0x79728480]-(20)-[UIButton:0x79727bc0]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725950 V:[UIButton:0x79728480]-(20)-[UIButton:0x79727bc0]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.310 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a993980 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x797270c0.midX == + 329>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797252e0 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x797270c0]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725290 H:[UIButton:0x797270c0(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79725290 H:[UIButton:0x797270c0(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.310 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a993980 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x797270c0.midX == + 329>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a9939b0 h=--& v=--& H:[UIButton:0x797270c0(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797252e0 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x797270c0]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797252e0 H:|-(48)-[UIButton:0x797270c0]   (Names: '|':Arounder.CategoriesBarView:0x797c7190 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.310 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7aad7710 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79727bc0.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7aad7a50 h=--& v=--& V:[UIButton:0x79727bc0(50)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a993510 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x797270c0.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797258d0 V:[UIButton:0x79727bc0]-(20)-[UIButton:0x797270c0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797258a0 V:[UIButton:0x797270c0(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797258a0 V:[UIButton:0x797270c0(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-17 12:49:14.311 Arounder[3992:10988727] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7aad7710 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79727bc0.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7aad7a50 h=--& v=--& V:[UIButton:0x79727bc0(50)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a993510 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x797270c0.midY == + 73>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797258d0 V:[UIButton:0x79727bc0]-(20)-[UIButton:0x797270c0]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797258d0 V:[UIButton:0x79727bc0]-(20)-[UIButton:0x797270c0]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iOS 8 safe**

**Before adding the buttons to view**

```
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

**After adding the buttons to view**

```
let views = ["button1": button1,
  "button2": button2,
  "button3": button3,
  "button4": button4,
  "button5": button5]

let buttonConstraintsH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "H:|-20-[button1]-20-[button2]-20-[button3]-20-[button4]-20-[button5]-20-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: views)

let button1ConstraintsV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:[button1]-17-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: views)

let button2ConstraintsV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:[button2]-17-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: views)

let button3ConstraintsV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:[button3]-17-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: views)

let button4ConstraintsV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:[button4]-17-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: views)

let button5ConstraintsV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:[button5]-17-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: views)

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([buttonConstraintsH, button1ConstraintsV, button2ConstraintsV, button3ConstraintsV, button4ConstraintsV, button5ConstraintsV])
```

and to have the same ratio (write it for each button):

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint( 
item:button1 
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
toItem:button1  
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
multiplier:1 
constant:0))
```

Comment: That doesn't working, the icons are really big, I want it to adjust the size of the icons too

Comment: @FS.O5 are you using image or backgroundimage for your buttons? Are they 50 x 50 px with my code?

Comment: Yes, they are. I'm using an image

Comment: I want all the buttons to fit exactly like on the iPhone 6/s screen, if the size needs to change that's ok, the goal is you make it fit inside my view on all the devices exactly the same. How can I do that?

Comment: @FS.O5 try this: button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5) and check if the image is smaller

Comment: It is, but too small, on the iPhone 6 it needs to be 50px, on the iPhone 5 it needs to be 45px and so on...
And the constraints doesn't do anything, I'll edit my question with the log error of it

Comment: Please take a look

Comment: @FS.O5 I updated my answer, let me know if it fix your errors.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here, I want the buttons to be places horizontally and not vertically. How can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121144/discussion-between-saintthread-and-fs-o5).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read more about NSLayoutAnchor ([read more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutAnchor_ClassReference/)) which is easier way of creating constraints.

short snippet:

self.add

```
self.addSubview(button1)
self.addSubview(button2)
self.addSubview(button3)
self.addSubview(button4)
self.addSubview(button5)

button1.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true
button1.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true
button1.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).active = true
button1.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topAnchor, constant: 50).active = true
....
```

Comment: That doesn't working, the icons are really big, I want it to adjust the size of the icons too